# Hansontable in Asp.Net , Repeat the table

Tags: asp.net, handsontable

I'm using Asp.net  ,

```
2957
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/Rf02nKuC
Click on the Load button, two handsontable panels appear, including an empty table and a table containing data.
How to display only 1 table with updated data. Pls!

Answer (score 0):

Remove any css that applies "padding" to the div containing the table.